# Docker Merge Volumes between host and image

Tags: docker

I have an application, in which I want to install into a docker image. This particular application has a folder for custom user's plugins. A user can put their plugins for our application there and we will load and execute them. We also ship our application with some plugins already. What I wanted is when I run docker mounting a volume with the `-v` options it still keeps the contents already in the image in a way like the contents from the image is merged with the ones in the host folder. Is that possible? Is there another solution that not involves a refactor in the app to support loading from multiple folders to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount them into your `/plugins/customplugin1`. In that case `ls plugins` should show

```
customplugin1
standardplugin
standardplugin2
```

Comment: You mean mounting referencing the file directly instead of the directory?

Comment: I would need to mount the /plugins and if I do that docker does not see the standard ones anymore:(